# VSTS Pipeline Deployment of ARM Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy an Azure ARM script in VSTS Pipeline.

I "Published" the Artifacts in the Build Step and Downloaded the Artifacts in the Release Step.  The Log seems to indicate that it found the ARM script (After much trial and error.  The prescribed manner found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceGroupDeploymentV2/README.md) does not seem to work at all).

I however get **Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern**

Incidentally, I get this error even if can't find the file (which makes sense..but not when it actually does find the file).  The ARM script deploys correctly when I deploy manually in Azure Portal.

I am using the **Azure Resource Group Deployment** step in the release pipeline.

I'm not sure what other information might help troubleshoot this, but request and hopefully I can get it to you.

Thanks

```
2018-12-14T18:32:06.6009951Z ##[section]Starting: Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action on ChrisGroup
2018-12-14T18:32:06.6015952Z 

==============================================================================
2018-12-14T18:32:06.6016124Z Task         : Azure Resource Group 
Deployment
2018-12-14T18:32:06.6016287Z Description  : Deploy an Azure resource manager (ARM) template to a resource group. You can also start, stop, delete, deallocate all Virtual Machines (VM) in a resource group
2018-12-14T18:32:06.6016444Z Version      : 2.141.4
2018-12-14T18:32:06.6016526Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-12-14T18:32:06.6016655Z Help         : [More Information] (https://aka.ms/argtaskreadme)
2018-12-14T18:32:06.6016801Z 
==============================================================================
2018-12-14T18:32:06.9610677Z Checking if the following resource group exists: ChrisGroup.
2018-12-14T18:32:07.2734470Z Resource group exists: true.
2018-12-14T18:32:07.2736899Z Creating deployment parameters.
2018-12-14T18:32:07.2809876Z The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\r1\a\IAC\ARM.json' is 'utf-8'
2018-12-14T18:32:07.3021166Z ##[error]Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern
2018-12-14T18:32:07.3030720Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action on ChrisGroup
```

As per request:

In the Template Parameters field I put
-dailyreports_name '$(IACWeb)' -dailyreportsapi_name '$(IACAPI)'

and OMG... It's supposed to be a path to a variables file.  UGH

Once I put into the Override Template Parameters, it works.

Microsoft should probable reword the label to "Template Parameters File"

Comment: What values are you providing to the step?

Comment: Thanks for the jog to the brain.  I completely didn't expect it to be anything other than the path to the template file.  The error message was quite misleading.

Comment: My problem was CaSe SeNsItiViTy. Check. Now check again, If it's after midnight go to bed and try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to put the parameters being passed in into the "Override template parameters".  The "Template parameters" field is actually a reference to a file location.

Comment: I am currently running into the same issue as you are, but I am not able to resolve it.
It used to work, but I added some .sql files to my application and now it suddenly throws the error "could not find any files", what exactly do you mean by "override template parameters"

Comment: It's one of the fields in the Azure Resource Group Deployment task.

Answer (score 1):

**When migrating from Classic to YAML deployments:**

Seeing:

*##[error]Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern*,

may be because you're referencing *Pipeline Artifacts* through the inputs `csmFile` and `csmParametersFile`, without actually having access to them in your pipelines stage. You may need to **download** the **artifacts first**, as seen in the second stage in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67961259/15354710).

**A quick check** to see if this is the case would be to **by-pass** your **artifacts**, and point the mentioned inputs directly to your *azuredeploy.json* and *azuredeploy.parameters.json* files where they are located in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

**##[error]Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern**

Check few things here :

1. check all parameter names (case sensitive) in the parameter file and template file.
2. if you are using yml file for azure devops pipeline,

   check all overrideParameters are correctly mentioned
   overrideParameters: '-environment "${{parameters.environment}}"'   #for example

   check csmParametersFile , csmFile path in the yml

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue turned out to be that I had to select specific build number while creating the release. If don't use specific build and just leave latest version option by default, then this error comes.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure all your variables are defined and correct!**

None of the previous answers helped me substantially. In my case it was because here:

```
- csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(template_file_location)'
```

I forgot to actually create the template_file_location variable. Once I created it in the Azure DevOps pipeline library and set it to the right path  (Deployment/Infrastructure/infrastructure.json in my case) it worked perfectly.

Unfortunately the Azure Pipelines error logging is not very satisfying, even if you enable the system diagnostics.